# Enterprise Mobile SSO in iOS - How to stay in the app

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to implement enterprise mobile SSO with our Identity Provider (OKTA). My goal is to have a smooth user experience; the user shouldn't leave our custom built app in order to login to the identity provider.

OKTA has a native iOS app that facilitates the process. During the login, it is possible to forward the user to the OKTA Native App, do the authentication and bring the user back to the custom app. The process looks like (image is taken from http://tech.blog.box.com/2013/03/rethinking-mobile-sso/):

[image: Native SSO approach]

What I am trying to is to avoid the opening of the Native SSO App (the first 2 steps). OKTA provides a REST API that allows the user to authenticate and create sessions programmatically (and more http://developer.okta.com/docs/getting_started/design_principles.html).

The question is: After creating a session with the native SSO App (OKTA) via its REST API and getting the auth token, can I authenticate directly with the Service Provider from my custom native iOS app?

Comment: If your app collects credentials, this isn't really single sign on... it's just authentication API usage. If you instead displayed a [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html) to the identity provider's sign on page, it is likely possible you can then perhaps read whatever token/cookie is returned to the browser and then programmatically use it behind the scenes (e.g. for API calls on the user's behalf). In this mode the user doesn't leave your app.

Comment: @scotth: What you said does make a lot of sense (authentication API vs. SSO). I am OK displaying provider's sign on page and reading the token/cookie that is returned. Actually, the only header that is returned is the `Referer`. I am not sure if this will be enough to authenticate the user. I will look into this part; if you have any insight on this one, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Okta provides a method for native app sso on iOS that allows the user start in your app, and have an SSO experience. In this case the Okta Mobile App serves as the identity provider. So long as the user has a session within Okta Mobile, they can access your custom native app without entering their credentials. If the user's session in Okta Mobile has ended, they can re-authenticate with their PIN.

More details on the standards-based framework (SAML + iOS) are available here:
http://developer.okta.com/docs/getting_started/saml_guidance.html#saml-for-mobile-native-apps
https://github.com/okta/okta-mobile-sdk

Comment: Yes, this approach requires leaving the app and switching over to the OKTA app. I am looking for a way to keep the user in the app.